# Foreach statement does not contain public definition for getEnumerator

Tags: c#, collision, monogame, enumerator

I am trying to implement collision between two paddles and I am getting the GetEnumerator error.

This is where I am getting the error:

```
foreach (Player item in paddle1)
{
    item.Update(gameTime);
    if (paddle2.CollisionSprite(item))
    {
        paddle2.Velocity = -paddle2.Velocity;
    }
}
```

And my Collision methods from Player:

```
public virtual Circle CollisionCircle
{
    get
    {
        return new Circle((int)(Position.X - SpriteOrigin.X * Scale), (int)(Position.Y - SpriteOrigin.Y * Scale),
                (int)(TextureImage.Width * Scale), (int)(TextureImage.Height * Scale));
    }
}

public bool CollisionSprite(Player sprite)
{
    return CollisionCircle.Intersects(sprite.CollisionCircle);
}
```

Comment: If paddle1 is not an IEnumerable (List, Array, etc), then this will not work. You need to post what type "paddle1" is.

Comment: Very unclear what `foreach (Player item in paddle1)` code should do...

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is because paddle1 is of type Player, not an IEnumerable. If you only have two players, you shouldn't have to loop and can just implement your function like this:

```
public void CollisionDetection(Player firstPlayer, Player secondPlayer)
{
    firstPlayer.Update(gameTime);
    secondPlayer.Update(gameTime);

    if (firstPlayer.CollisionSprite(secondPlayer))
    {
        firstPlayer.Velocity = -firstPlayer.Velocity;
        secondPlayer.Velocity = -secondPlayer.Velocity;
    }
}
```

Usage would be:

```
CollisionDetection(paddle1, paddle2);
```